# Facebook SDK v4 error : Class 'Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStreamHttpClient' not found

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I added the facebook's SDK into my PHP project and i try to get user's data
But I’m getting the following error even I have included all the required library files in the correct directories. But no matter what I do

```
Class 'Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStreamHttpClient' not found in  

C:\..\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php
```

this is my code :

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\AccessToken;


 if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])){
    unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);
 }

$app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$redirect_url='http://localhost/test/ex/fbloginlogout/';
//3.Initialize application, create helper object and get fb sess
 FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
 $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
 $sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
//check if facebook session exists
if(isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])){
    $sess = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);
}

$logout = 'http://localhost/test/ex/newfblogin&logout=true';

    if(isset($sess)){

        $_SESSION['fb_token']=$sess->getToken();
        $request = new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/me');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
        $name = $graph->getName();
        $id = $graph->getId();
        $image = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?width=300';
        $email = $graph->getProperty('email');
        echo "hi $name <br>";
        echo "your email is $email <br><Br>";
        echo "<img src='$image' /><br><br>";
        echo "<a href='".$logout."'><button>Logout</button></a>";
    }else{

        echo '<a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl(array('email')).'" >Login with facebook</a>';
    }
```

Comment: According to your error, you're trying to go up one folder from 'C:\', which is impossible.

Comment: Why not just use the autoload file that is included in the SDK. Then all require statements are not needed anymore

Comment: @WizKid even i used the autoload file i still have the  same error

Comment: So what does your code look like?

Comment: @WizKid i add `define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php';` but i get this error `Failed opening required 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in ..`

Comment: @souzanne are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @tehspark it's ok, I solve it